# function que no funciona en WordPress con WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, wordpress-theme

Estoy intentando reordenar los datos de `woocommerce_single_product_summary`
para mostrarlos de una forma personalizada en las paginas de archivos de productos.

Para ello realice el siguiente codigo php de funciones en functions.php del theme Hello.

Pero no me funciona.
Alguien podria guiarme con algun posible error?
Desde ya muchas gracias

```
function reordenar_campos_ficha_productos() {
  remove_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5
  );
  remove_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10
  );
  remove_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30
  );

  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'mostrar_categoria_producto', 6
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'mostrar_campo_banco', 7
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 8
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'mostrar_campo_variedad1', 9
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10
  );
  add_action(
    'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
    'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30
  );
}

// Mostrar categoría del producto
function mostrar_categoria_producto() {
  global $product;
  echo '<p class="product-category">' . 
    $product->get_category()->name . '</p>';
}

// Mostrar campo personalizado "banco"
function mostrar_campo_banco() {
  global $product;
  echo '<p class="product-custom-field">' .
    $product->get_meta('banco') . '</p>';
}

// Mostrar campo personalizado "variedad1"
function mostrar_campo_variedad1() {
  global $product;
  echo '<p class="product-custom-field">' .
    $product->get_meta('variedad1') . '</p>';
}

add_action(
  'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary',
  'reordenar_campos_ficha_productos', 1
);
```